# What is the difference between chmod and chattr?

Tags: chmod

Solaris operating system does not have `chattr`, it uses `chmod` instead. Also on Windows. Because when you're changing attributes of a file you're changing what you or other users can do with it, thus the meaning of `chmod`.

So do we really need `chattr`? and how is it different to `chmod`?

Comment: "Solaris operating system does not have chattr, it uses chmod instead. Also on Windows." Not our problem ;)  `chattr` is more powerful than `chmod`: chmod does not always have a method to set "immutable".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `chmod` refers to file permissions for users, groups and others:

  read
  write
  execute
- `chattr` refers to attributes regardless users or groups, some of the attributes are:

  `a` → Append only
  `i` → Immutable
  `c` → File automatically compressed in kernel

  Take a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr) for `chattr`.

Comment: `chmod` with `-w` is for removing write permissions

Comment: Oops removed it. Yes but not on solaris ;)

Answer (score 1):

### Extended attributes

The `chattr` allows to change [extended file attributes](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/pages/extattrs.html), which are [not supported by all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes#Linux) *nix operating systems or all GNU/Linux distributions or file systems.

Conversely, the `chmod` command can only change standard file system attributes.

Answer (score 0):

At least because:

```
Not  all  flags are supported or utilized by all filesystems;
```

The second thing - this question is a kind of trilling, because there is no chattr (these bits like linux has support) in solaris.